# Post from html form to onesignal php Api?

Tags: php, html, api, onesignal

I was wondering how can I make this simple form work with Onesignal Api.
Html form to post the writing message into onesignal php file.

```
<form action="one.php" method="post">
 <p>Your Message: <input type="text" name="Message" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

one.php

```
<?PHP
  function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
      "en" => 'Message' <-the message field I need to replace via form
      );

    $fields = array(
      'app_id' => "896068a9-2b83-4a1d-9c6a-53300261e7d5",
      'included_segments' => array('All'),
      'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
      'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                           'Authorization: Basic NTkyZDEyNjktOGJiNS60YmQ5LT2hZDktMWQ5MzA1ZjY3Mjcz'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
  }

  $response = sendMessage();
  $return["allresponses"] = $response;
  $return = json_encode( $return);

  print("\n Message Send");
?>
```

I know it may be simple for someone here I can't seem to find a way.
I have tried replacing 'Message' with `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['Message']); ?>` but all I get is error.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should learn a bit more how functions work
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

```
<?php

function sendMessage($message){

    $content = array(
        "en" => $message
    );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
        'included_segments' => array('All'),
        'data' => array(
            "foo" => "bar"
        ),
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);

    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj'
        )
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage($_POST['Message']);

$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode( $return);

print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer it is probably a suboptimal solution but it works, first change your html to avoid confusion.

```
<!--Lets change input element to: name="mytext" -->

<form action="one.php" method="post">
   <p>Your Message: <input type="text" name="mytext" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Now in the PHP file declare 'mytext' as an empty variable above your first function, then replace the variable in your array with the correct syntax.

```
<?php
    $mytext = "";
    function sendMessage(){    
        $content = array(
            "en" => $_POST['mytext']
        );
//etc...
```

Finally let the user know the notification was succesful, give it a nice format with css and at last but not the least, I will suggest you to include some other important data such as a title, badge image, icon, an optional URL, buttons, and probably a big picture(you can do this, by modifying the $fields array), some of this values such as the badge or the icon, can be hardcoded in your php file, since you dont have to replace them every time.